# How to collect values of an UIInput component inside an UIData component in bean's action method?

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, richfaces

I'm trying to collect values of an `UIInput` component inside an `UIData` component during bean's action method in order to validate duplicate values. I tried to bind the `UIInput` component to a bean property and getting its value, but it prints `null`. If I place it outside the datatable, then it prints the expected value. Is there something wrong with the datatable?

```
<rich:dataTable binding="#{bean.table}" value="#{bean.data}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Field1" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText binding="#{bean.input}" value="#{item.field1}" />
    </h:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Here's the backing bean code:

```
private UIData table;
private UIInput input;

public void save() {
    System.out.println(input.getId() + " - " + input.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the datatable. There's **only one** `UIInput` component in the JSF component tree whose state get changed everytime whenever the parent `UIData` component iterates over every item of the model. The state is thus only available *during* the `UIData` iteration and not before or after. You're trying to access the value of a single component in the bean's action method while the parent `UIData` component isn't iterating over it, so the values will always return `null`.

You need to visit the component tree by [`UIComponent#visitTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#visitTree%28javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext,%20javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback%29) on the `UIData` and collect the information of interest in the `VisitCallback` implementation.

```
table.visitTree(VisitContext.createVisitContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()), new VisitCallback() {
    @Override
    public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target) {
        if (target instanceof UIInput) {
            UIInput input = (UIInput) target;
            System.out.println("id: " + input.getId());
            System.out.println("value: " + input.getValue());
        }

        return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
    }
});
```

By the way, you'd normally perform the validation with a normal `Validator` on the `UIInput` component or, in this particular case maybe better, a `ValueChangeListener`. This allows for easier invalidation and message handling.